# MS SQL select multiple columns based on the MAX(ID) with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to merge two queries. The aim is to get a recordset that has unique customer emails along with their name and the title for their latest listing based on MAX(ID).

Using DISTINCT I can get the email and ID but obviously adding the title breaks this.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(EV_ID) As EV_ID, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName
FROM tblEvents ev
INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID
WHERE (
    CUS_IsAdmin = 'y'
    AND CUS_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_EndDate >= '2012/7/5 12:00:00 AM'
    AND EV_ContactEmail <> ''
    )
GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail
```

I've found some posts on here that say indicate I need to do a self join but I cannot get it to return the same amount of records but with the title, it returns many more.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(EV_ID) As EV_ID, ev.EV_Title, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName
FROM tblEvents ev
INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EV_Title, MAX(EV_ID) AS MaxID
    FROM tblEvents
    GROUP BY EV_Title
) groupedev ON ev.EV_Title = groupedev.EV_Title AND ev.EV_ID = groupedev.MaxID
WHERE (
    CUS_IsAdmin = 'y' 
    AND CUS_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_EndDate >= '2012/7/5 12:00:00 AM'
    AND EV_ContactEmail <> ''
)
GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail, ev.EV_Title
```

Can anyone advise what is wrong with it?

Comment: can you also provide your db structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.EV_ID, e.EV_ContactEmail, e.EV_CusName
FROM
        events AS e
    INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT MAX(EV_ID) As EV_ID
          FROM tblEvents ev
            INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus 
              ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID
          WHERE CUS_IsAdmin = 'y'
            AND CUS_Live = 'y' 
            AND EV_Live = 'y' 
            AND EV_EndDate >= '20120705T00:00:00'   --- notice the unambiguous
            AND EV_ContactEmail <> ''               --- datetime format
          GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail
        ) AS tmp
      ON tmp.EV_ID = e.EV_ID ;
```

Comment: This query works perfectly, you've saved me from having a bad Friday afternoon! thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT EV_ID, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName, EV_Title
FROM tblEvents ev
    INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus 
        ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(EV_ID) AS  MaxID
                FROM tblEvents
                GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail) sub
        ON ev.EV_ID = sub.MaxID
WHERE CUS_IsAdmin = 'y'
    AND CUS_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_Live = 'y' 
    AND EV_EndDate >= '2012/7/5 12:00:00 AM'
    AND EV_ContactEmail <> ''
```

Comment: Great, this looks good although your first query was correct in grouping by EV_ContactEmail as one admin (customer) can post on behalf of others. This does return 24 fewer rows than the total of unique EV_ContactEmail's, is there a way of testing why that is?

Comment: Yes it works for me. I would just like to know why there are 24 fewer records than expected based on a distinct query just selecting the emails. There are 639 distinct emails but this query returns 615 records.

Comment: So the query `SELECT DISTINCT EV_ContactEmail FROM tblEvents` returns 639 records?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear @Kevin. When I run `SELECT DISTINCT EV_ContactEmail FROM tblEvents INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID WHERE (...)` I get 639 records. When I run yours I get 615. I don't think the extra columns should affect the record count, maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: Hmm... it's difficult to say. They should return the same number of records. If you could post your data structures and a sample of the records that show in your query but not in mine, that would help me identify where the problem is.

Comment: I compared this query with @ypercube and I can see the 24 records but can't see why they're not in there. Thanks for your help with this though.

Comment: This query and mine are similar. This has the conditions in the external query and thus shows the events with maximum ID for every contactEmail, and then chooses (from them) only those that match the conditions. Mine has the conditions in the internal subquery, so first finds events that match the conditions, and then chooses the ones wih maximum ID for every contactEmail. That's why there's a difference.

Comment: There are 24 contactEmails that their (maximum ID) events do not match the conditions (either they are not Admins or that event is not Live etc.) but have other events (with lower IDs) that match the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `distinct`, you can first order by `EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName, EV_ID desc` and then group all other columns

```
SELECT MAX(EV_ID) As EV_ID, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName
FROM 
(
   SELECT EV_ID As EV_ID, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName 
   FROM tblEvents ev 
   INNER JOIN tblCustomers cus ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID 
   WHERE (     
      CUS_IsAdmin = 'y'     
      AND CUS_Live = 'y'      
      AND EV_Live = 'y'      
      AND EV_EndDate >= '2012/7/5 12:00:00 AM'     
      AND EV_ContactEmail <> ''     
   ) 
   ORDER BY EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName, EV_ID DESC -- you can add title also here before ev_id
)
GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName  -- if you need title in query, also add title here
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. It simply orders a recordset with lots of duplicates.

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes after `GROUP BY`

Comment: @DeanCarslake I guess u missed the part to group all records. I have modified the query. this should work fine.

Comment: This "trick" may work in MySQL. But it doesn't in SQL-Server (which is clever enough to identify that `ORDER BY` is redundant inside the subquery)

Comment: interesting! wasn't aware of that...thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change 'inner join' to 'left outer join' : 
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(EV_ID) As EV_ID, EV_ContactEmail, EV_CusName 
FROM tblEvents ev 
 
left outer join tblCustomers cus ON cus.CUS_ID = ev.EV_CustomerID  
WHERE ( 
 
    CUS_IsAdmin = 'y' 
 
    AND CUS_Live = 'y'  
    AND EV_Live = 'y'  
 
    AND EV_EndDate >= '2012/7/5 12:00:00 AM' 
    AND EV_ContactEmail <> '' 
    )
GROUP BY EV_ContactEmail

Comment: It has to be an inner join as I require admin-only records, hence the IsAdmin = 'y' filter.